# Laravel HTTP Client POST request doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, httpclient

So here's my code on the controller:

```
public function postAgenda(Request $request)
    {
        $response = Http::withToken('31|14gfAJHaXv6qU3x4WwxAwE8Txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')->post('https://myapi.tld/AgendaCrt', [
            'Agenda' => [
                'hari' => 'senin',
                'tgl' => '2022-02-18',
                'waktu' => '16:00:00',
                'lokasi' => 'bogor',
                'kegiatan' => 'Belajar HTTP Client',
                'user_id' => '9'
            ]
        ]);

        return response()->json([
            'Success' => $response
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

And here's the route on the web.php route:

```
Route::get('/post', [AgendaController::class, 'postAgenda']);
```

When i try to run it on browser, the response was success but it doesn't send any data, like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Try `'Success' => $response->body()` instead.

Comment: It still doesn't work tho :(, thanks btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method `Route::get` to `Route::post`

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's HTTP client wrapper does not throw exceptions on client or server errors (`400` and `500` level responses from servers). You may determine if one of these errors was returned using the `successful`, `clientError`, or `serverError` methods.

Or..

The `throw` method returns the response instance if no error occurred, allowing you to chain other operations onto the throw method:

```
$response = Http::withToken('31|14gfAJHaXv6qU3x4WwxAwE8Txxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
    ->post('https://myapi.tld/AgendaCrt', [
        'Agenda' => [
            'hari' => 'senin',
            'tgl' => '2022-02-18',
            'waktu' => '16:00:00',
            'lokasi' => 'bogor',
            'kegiatan' => 'Belajar HTTP Client',
            'user_id' => '9'
        ]
    ])
    ->throw()
    ->json();

return response()->json([
    'Success' => $response
];
```